# Proving properties of Laplacian matrices

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, laplacian

I have to prove that

$$L = \sum_{i,j \in E} (e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T.$$

where $e_i$ is the vector of length $n$ that is one in the $i^\mathrm{th}$ entry, and is zero in every other entry (i.e., $e_i$ is the $i^\mathrm{th}$ column of the $n \times n$ identity matrix).

My first question is, can we rewrite it following as,

$$L = \sum_{i,j \in E} (e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T = (e_i-e_j)^2$$

If so, can we than say 
$$L = \sum_{i,j \in E} (e_i-e_j)^2 = \hat{e}^TL\hat{e} $$

Where $\hat{e}$ represents the vector $e_i - e_j$. Not sure if I am expressing myself correctly here.

Comment: I think I see where I am supposed to go with this.

Comment: eigen values are the same despite being transposed. 
Which allows me to have the summation value squared. 

Letting e_i be a vector that is a one in the ith entry and and a zero everywhere else, and having my graph connected.

I have that the null(L) = Lx = span(e) = lambda e 
and aij entries are 1 (connected graph)

And perhaps through this I relate the vector e, with the nullspace, which I then expand and then make it

 summation (xi-xj)^2 = L

maybe...?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the correct answer.

$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} x^TLx = \sum_{i,j \in E} x^T(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^Tx = x^T\bigg(\sum_{i,j \in E} (e_i - e_j)(e_i - e_j)\bigg)x =  x^T \bigg(\sum_{i,j \in E} (e_i-e_j)^2\bigg)x = \sum_{i,j \in E} x^TLx  \geq 0 $$